# Generating self signed certificate for testing nginx via vagrant vm

Tags: ssl, nginx, vagrant, puppet

I generated a Vagrant VM for testing using the excellent [PuPHPet](https://puphpet.com/) tool. I've done some puppet hacking previously, but I'm stuck on generating a self-signed SSL certificate for use with the VM. I'm familiar with doing it purely via openssl commands, but I'm looking for a puppet solution.

I've browsed a bit of the puppet ssl source, but I'm not sure this is the right avenue to explore: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/tree/master/lib/puppet/ssl

I also stumbled on this shell script that the author used with puppet:
http://www.codenes.com/blog/?p=300

Useful, but not exactly a puppet configuration.

The lazy way would be to fire up the VM and generate the certificate manually. Then, use a `file` resource declaration to copy the previously generated certificate when launching the VM. Not ideal, I'd prefer more automation.

Answer (score 4):

Author of PuPHPet here.

I'm actually trying to solve this issue within PuPHPet itself :)

The problem is that the self-signed cert would be generated each time you $ vagrant up a new instance. I don't know what kind of warnings your browser would throw at you, but I'm certainly willing to try.

Follow me on twitter @juantreminio and I'll make sure to spam all my followers when the feature has been added!

Comment: For testing, I'm happy to ignore the warnings. I resorted to a non-puppet way of generating a certificate: https://gist.github.com/ericcholis/6123367

Comment: Any advances or news on adding self-signed certs to PuPHPet yet? This feature would make my year :)

Comment: @JasonMortonNZ v2 is coming out in a few hours, can you open a ticket? it should be much easier for me to add this now.